# ASCII characters in C

Tags: c, char, ascii, wchar-t

I'm trying to save a character from the cyrillic alphabet in a char.
When I take a string from the console it saves it in the char array successfully but just initializing it doesn't seem to work. I get "programName.exe has stopped working" when trying to run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test(){
    char test = 'Я';
    printf("%s",test);
}

void main(){
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    test();
}


fgets ( books[booksCount].bookTitle, 80, stdin ); // this seems to be working ok with ascii.
```

I tried using wchar_t but I get the same results.

Comment: Now go read a beginner C tutorial about `printf()`, and read its documentation as well. Also, turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: Passing "%s" to printf tells it to expect a string parameter, but you are passing a char.

Comment: anyways printing it with %c is giving me a question mark

Comment: You need to make sure your *input* character `'Я'` is stored in a single byte as well. Chances are it appears encoded as UTF-8 in your source code. Look up the character code for `Я` in code page 1251 and use that instead of the literal character.

Comment: Read http://utf8everwhere.org/ and remember that in 2018 (and even 2014) it is reasonable to use UTF-8 everywhere. Then the `в` - the last letter of your family name - is not a single byte in UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Russian Windows which uses [Windows-1251 codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) by default, you can print the character encoded as a single byte using the old `printf` but you need to make sure that the source code uses the same cp1251 charset. Don't save as Unicode.

But the preferred way should be using [`wprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx) with wide char string

```
void test() {
    wchar_t  test_char   = L'Я';
    wchar_t *test_string = L"АБВГ"; // or LPCWSTR test_string
    wprintf(L"%c\n%s", test_char, test_string);
}
```

This time you need to save the file as Unicode (UTF-8 or UTF-16)

UTF-8 may be better, but it's trickier on Windows. Moreover if you use UTF-8 you cannot use a `char` to store Я because it needs more than 1 byte. You must use a `char*` instead

Note that [`main` must return int, not `void`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/995714), and the above `fgets` must be called from inside some function

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved, doing

```
void test()
{
    char test = 'Я';
    putchar(test);
}
```

But there is a catch: Since 'Я' is not an ASCII character, you might need to set appropriate locale before. 
Moreover, only ASCII characters 32 - 126 are guaranteed to be printable, and the same symbol, on all systems.

Comment: `only ASCII characters 32 - 126 are guaranteed to be printable, and the same symbol, on all systems` is wrong. Even ASCII isn't mandated by the C standard. For example there are many systems that use EBCDIC instead of ASCII